# Trying to write a program that solves a snake cube

Tags: c#

So Im a first year appretice in application development and my task is to write a program in C# that can solve a 3x3x3 snake cube. I got a general idea how Im gonna do it but Im stuck at a specific point. There are 17 blocks of 2 or 3 cubes in the snake which are all connected by a string.  My question is how do I show my program how the snake is constructed. What I mean by that is Im looking for a way to tell my program that the snake isnt a straight line but rather well... a snake. I have started by turning each block into an array which has the lenght of the number of cubes in one block. I also gave each cube a number which determines if it is a cube thats connected straight to another or on the side.
It looks like that:

```
        snakePart1 = new int[3] { 1, 1, 0 };
        snakePart2 = new int[2] { 0, 0 };
        snakePart3 = new int[2] { 0, 0 };
        snakePart4 = new int[3] { 0, 1, 0 };
        snakePart5 = new int[2] { 0, 0 };
        snakePart6 = new int[3] { 0, 1, 0 };
        snakePart7 = new int[2] { 0, 0 };
        snakePart8 = new int[2] { 0, 0 };
        snakePart9 = new int[3] { 0, 1, 0 };
        snakePart10 = new int[3] { 0, 1, 0 };
        snakePart11 = new int[2] { 0, 0 };
        snakePart12 = new int[2] { 0, 0 };
        snakePart13 = new int[2] { 0, 0 };
        snakePart14 = new int[3] { 0, 1, 0 };
        snakePart15 = new int[3] { 0, 1, 0 };
        snakePart16 = new int[3] { 0, 1, 0 };
        snakePart17 = new int[3] { 0, 1, 1 };
        snakeParts = new List<int[]>();
```

Hope I made my problem clear and thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the snake cube?

Comment: This sounds to me like you'd benefit representing snakeCubePart as a class or struct that has 6 faces and up to two references (the connections) to faces of other snakeCupeParts. assuming you are talking about this puzzle: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_cube

Comment: It is not clear what all these ones and zeroes represent.

Comment: @Dialecticus the ones are the cubes that connect to each other in a straight line the zeros are the ones that are corner pieces

Comment: If you have more than one corner piece then some information is missing there. It's the direction of the every corner piece except the first one.